# NEW T4 Controller Template in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, t4, code-templates

As you know to create new t4 templates in MVC, need to add `CodeTemplates` folder to project. There are two main subfolders 1-`AddController`, 2-`AddView` I always use `AddView` folder to add new templates to generate custom views, know I need new template to generate controllers, but when I add new `tt` file to `AddController` folder, there is no any new option in templates of new controller, there is always 3 options:

[image]

So how can I add new option to Add Controller window to use my custom Controller Template?
Or if I try wrong way, what is your suggestion to use Template to generate controllers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you can only extend the Add Controller dialog with using the [MvcScaffolding](http://mvcscaffolding.codeplex.com/) nuget package:

From the [asp.net page](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3#BM_MvcScaffolding):

> The ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update includes great Visual Studio support
>   for this scaffolding system, such as:
>
> - Add Controller Dialog now supports full automatic scaffolding of Create, Read, Update, and Delete controller actions and corresponding
>     views. By default, this scaffolds data access code using EF Code
>     First.
> - **Add Controller Dialog supports extensible scaffolds via NuGet packages such as MvcScaffolding. This allows plugging in custom
>     scaffolds into the dialog which would allow you to create scaffolds
>     for other data access technologies such as NHibernate or even JET with
>     ODBCDirect if you’re so inclined!**

You can start learning about MvcScaffolding [from this article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/).

Comment: I ask a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838142/put-all-methods-in-one-tt-file-and-use-it-in-another-t4-files-in-codetemplates would you please check it